# Invalid WS Security Header - IRS ACA SOAP Request using IBM integration BUS / Message Broker

Tags: web-services, soap, irs

I am trying to send a SOAP request to IRS's ACA A2A web service using IBM integration BUS.

The request I am trying to post is matching the standards mentioned in the IRS guide but I am receiving 'TPE1122' SOAP fault message. Does anyone use IIB or message broker to post the ACA requests to IRS?

I use policy set & policy set bindings to generate the signature.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the TokenType option to 'STRREF' in the 'Message Part Policy' section of the Policy Set Binding to generate the KeyInfo Object.

I was able to successfully get through the TPE1122 error for the ACABulkTransmitterStatusService.

However, the same option does not work for ACABulkTransmitterRequest Service. Apparently the schema validation is different for the 2 web services on the IRS side. Have a sent a note to the help desk and waiting for the response!